# Can github clone siblings be made invisible to each others users?

Tags: github

Let's say I make a repo called parent, and I clone it twice, `child1` and `child2`.

Then I invite `person1` to have edit capabilities to `child1`, and `person2` to have edit capabilities on `child2`.

Can I guarantee, via some combination of permission settings, that `person1` cannot view the `child2` clone, and `person2` cannot view the `child1` clone?

These are all private repos.

The goal is to have a teacher copy of coursework skeleton code, and students that can clone it and make changes and upload to their clones, but that cannot see each others' work.

Comment: The usual practice would be for the students to each fork your repo into their own account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better option would be to ask each student to make a forked from you repo and then each student will have a forked repo of his own and you can ask them to add you are collaborator on that forked private repo.

People can cheat by sending a copy over email. It can't be stopped.

Comment: settings aside the issue of "there's always cheating", does this actually prevent one fork's owner from seeing the other forks, though?

Comment: You can ask each student to set there repo as private and you as collaborator, this way only you and the student will have access.  No one else will know if the fork exists expect youv since you own parent repo     .  Here is link for making private fork 
   https://gist.github.com/0xjac/85097472043b697ab57ba1b1c7530274

Answer (score 1):

If those are private repositories, any user won't be able to see them unless they are explicitly added as collaborator (as in "[Inviting collaborators to a personal repository](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository)")

In your case, you could duplicate your skeleton repository, uploading it to student1_repo, student2_repo, and so on, each private repositories.

Then you invite student1 to student1_repo, student2 to student2_repo, and so on.

Each student won't be able to see any other private repository of yours.

The advantage over asking students to make a fork is that you control who access to what, and make sure each repository is indeed only for that specific student, without the possibility for said student to "invite" others to their fork.

---

So again:

- each student repository is not a fork
- each student repository start with the same history as the original skeleton repository.
- each new repository creation can be scripted, using [Github cli tool](https://github.com/cli/cli)
- you can push updated to all repositories in one push (but they will need to merge that new modification in their own branch)

That is:

```
git clone https://github.com/me/skeleton

# for each student
gh repo create student1_repo --private --enable-wiki=false
gh repo adduser student1 student1_repo
git remote set-url --add --push all https://github.com/me/student1_repo
```

Note: gh repo adduser does not exist yet: [this script (issue `cli/cli` 1531)](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/1531#issuecomment-732502183) will call the relevant GitHub API.

```
# for any update from your skeleton to your student repositories:

git push all master:update
# for each student:
gh pr create --title "Add this to your main" --body "Merge this PR" \
             -a student1 -H update
```

Comment: So the issue with this is that I did this last semester, and I made a separate student account for myself, completely separate from my main account that owned the parent, and yet as that "fake student" account, i was able to see the other forks, even when uninvited. Are you positive this works? I'm trying to figure out if I messed something up when making my fake student account that would explain why I could see other private forks off the parent, even though it was a separate account.

Comment: My answer does not include fork, but new separate private repository, one per student, where only one student is invited. Now *that* should resist your fake account inquisitive eye.

Comment: hmm, though that prevents me from being able to update the parent and push it to all the child forks...

Comment: @eruciform Why? Those repositories are pushed from the skeleton repo in the first place. So you can do exactly what you described.

Comment: @eruciform Note: everything can be scripted. I have included the relevant commands in the updated answer.

Comment: so, i accepted the other answer because it's technically what i asked for, but you put a ton of effort into this, and i'll probably use it in the future, if not for this purpose. i'm opening a second bounty and will award it to you for your work. have to wait 23 hours to be able to do so. thank you so much for putting in the effort to document this for me.

Comment: @eruciform No problem. Glad you have found a solution which works.